# Interpretable code using Newton-Raphson Method

Tags: java, newtons-method

I am having troubles with a Java code that must calculate the root square of a given parameter.
However,after some research I found a code that I don't know how was implemented properly.

```
 // read in the command-line argument
    double c = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
    double epsilon = 1.0e-15;  // relative error tolerance
    double t = c;              // estimate of the square root of c

    // repeatedly apply Newton update step until desired precision is achieved
    while (Math.abs(t - c/t) > epsilon *t) {
        t = (c/t + t) / 2.0;
    }

    // print out the estimate of the square root of c
    System.out.println(t);
```

1. The first thing that I don't understand completely is why they are dividing by two on the 8th line.

   `t = (c/t + t) / 2.0;`
2. The second thing which I do not understand is the condition from the *while loop*, to be more precise:

   `while(Math.abs(t - c/t) > epsilon*t)`
3. Wouldn't be necessary to have only:

   `while(Math.abs(t - c/t) > epsilon)`

Comment: Where did you get that `epsilon*t` from? What does this document/article wrote about this expression and why the factor `*t` is used?

Answer (score 0):

```
t = (c/t + t) / 2.0;
```

This is used to calculate the average/mean of the two values `c/t` and `t`. The value is stored in the variable `t` for the next loop iteration. Use a `System.out.println()` call inside the `while` loop to check the values of `t` and `c/t` before this line and the values after this line.